# `Cannot find symbol` in IntelliJ 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have use the IntelliJ Scala plugin before, in 13 and 13.1. I upgraded to 14, and it doesn't work anymore for my SBT project.

For all Scala standard lib stuff, I see errors like "Cannot find symbol scala.Option".

[at scala project, compiler error - Cannot resolve symbol List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960227/at-scala-project-compiler-error-cannot-resolve-symbol-list) says I need to have the Scala facet for my module. I looked in facets, and Scala wasn't an option.

[image]

I've uninstalled IntelliJ and the Scala plugin and my settings and the projects files multiple times, but still happens.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not a solution, so not posting it as such; I've had better luck with Scala-IDE. IntelliJ wrote their own Scala parsing layer, and as such, frequently fails miserably any time macros are involved or other advanced type programming. Scala-IDE (for eclipse) uses the presentation compiler from the same compiler building your code. It can handle anything the compiler can handle, macros included.

Comment: @TimHarper, interesting. I used Eclipse and found that the Scala support was significantly worse, but that was years ago. I may give that a try.

Comment: I feel you @PaulDraper, I think IntelliJ Scala 1.1/1.1.1 is broken, 1.0 worked well for me (IDEA 14). Hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using the nightly builds of the Scala plugin.

The fixes have now been incorporated into the stable versions.

Answer (score 4):

the new scala plugin for intellij 14 removed the facet and replaced it with Scala SDK library, see [blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/10/30/scala-plugin-update-for-intellij-idea-14-rc-is-out/)

for sbt project, I guess the best bet is to re-create your project by:

File -> open -> select the build.sbt of your project in popup -> delete existing project and import

Comment: I can't see that option, do you have a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when a Java module calls an Scala object. The issue was from the wrong setup in Source Folders; the Scala source was in src/main/scala/..., but in the `Project Structure`, the Source Folders were setup as `src` by default. When I changed it as `src/main/scala`, the Java module can find the Scala object correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just had to reload the IDE...